# Is it possible to use camel/jbpm with slurm computational grid?

Tags: apache-camel, drools, jbpm

In HPC we use often `SLURM` as `workload manager`. I would like to know if `camel or jbpm-camel` can to communicate to `SLURM` ?

I found `apache spark` but nothing about `slurm`.

I am interested by any documentation on this subjects.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The relation to Drools being what, exactly?

Comment: drools has drools-camel to make smart workflow. I hope to find a working solution using drools-camel

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about-- what API/RPC options are available for SLURM? If it is completely proprietary, than there probably isn't an available Camel component, but one could be put together using one of the low-level socket camel components, such as mina / netty / etc.